# Selecionar campo SELECT com jquery

Tags: php, jquery

Estou utilizando o comando

`.find(input[type='text'],input[type='url'],input[type='radio'])` , para encontrar campos de formulários em um form.

gostaria de procurar por campos `<select>`

Qual a notação que utilizo no `.find()` para também procurar campos do tipo `<select>?`

Answer (score 1):

Adiciona o select ai na lista

```
$.find("input[type='text'],input[type='url'],input[type='radio'], select")
```

Answer (score 1):

Primordialmente você deve adicionar o select na lista, oque fará que ele seja pego junto, assim como dito em uma resposta anterior.

os principais seletores no jquery são:

`$('elemento')` para selecionar todos os elemenentos de um tipo

`$('.classe')` para selecionar todos os elemenentos com uma classe

`$('#id')` para selecionar o elemenento com esse id (ou o primeiro com esse id no DOM)

caso deseje saber mais sobre seletores jquery segue um [link com mais explicações](https://www.devmedia.com.br/introducao-aos-seletores-da-jquery/27362)

Answer (score 0):

Para procura tag no DOM via jQuery você só precisa adicionar o nome da tag a buscar do jQuery. Exemplo:

```
$('select').each(function(index, item) {
  alert($(this).find('option').length);
});
```

o Código acima irá dar uma alerta com a quantidade de `option` de cada `select` no DOM

Comment: a questão toda que quando faço a procura, estou querendo procurar campos do formulário, exemplo que coloquei, procurou campos inputs de tipos diferentes. Estou precisando saber a notação em jquery para procura de campo <select> .